# Is there any bad affect on heavy queries on tables that are placed in different filegroups?

Tags: sql-server, filegroup

I need to split tables into multiple file groups. My queries contains join between these tables that will be in different file groups.
Does this cause bad performance on my queries?

Comment: "I need to split tables into multiple file groups." why?

Comment: *Does this cause bad performance on my queries*, No. Although no one is in a better postition to test it than you are.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Some tables are archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My queries contains join between these tables that will be in different file groups. Does this cause bad performance on my queries?

No.  If you split a database into two separate filegroups on the same disk, you should see no material performance difference.  Obviously if you put one of these filegroups on a slower disk queries could be impacted.